Car loan pre approved but not finalized
I bought a car on April 11 2024. I was pre approved . Car dealership did not finalize paper work. My loan sitting in pre approval. Car dealership closed

If you were trying to ask something, it seems like your post was cut-off mid-question...

Closed as in they have gone home for the evening, or closed as in the car lot is empty and there's a "for sale" sign on the showroom?

Did you take possession of a car? Does your pre-approval have an expiration?

In the US, pre-approval means only "we don't see any obvious reason we wouldn't loan money to you, and if we do offer you a loan here's the interest rate we expect we would charge." It doesn't commit you to taking that loan; it probably doesn't commit the lender to offering that loan.
Pre-approval mostly reassures the buyer that a loan is probably available and affordable, and reassures the seller that they can negotiate on the assumption that you will in fact be able to pay.
And if you would be getting the loan through the dealer, it lets the dealer know how much they will be paid for steering the customer to this bank and this offer.
Which brings up an important point. Never include the loan in your price negotiations for the car. Instead, make the best deal you can for the car, then see if the dealer can offer better financing than you can get elsewhere. That forces them to compete for both sales, rather than giving you a good deal on one because they're giving you a bad deal on the other. Loans through dealers are often sales tools, not just conveniences.
